# How to upload a django project to heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have been trying to upload my Django app to the Heroku for 3 hours but it is showing me an error. I am doing everything as shown in the documentation but I am getting this error.

> error: src refspec master does not match any error: failed to push
> some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/share-good.git'
> could anyone help me with that please??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Probably you have some issues with your commit branch name or your commits.

Answer (score 0):

add all files in .git and commit changes. by

`git add .`

`git commit -am "initial commit"`

later push to heroku git by

`git push heroku master`

if still gives the error use --force at end.

`git push heroku master --force`

if still not solve try

```
git fetch --all
```

again push it.

`git push heroku master --force`

you must follow heroku documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python.

Comment: Thanks for the full comment I will do all of them and then if I meet some error again I will return again thanks again.